# How to make ContextMenu in NewView:NSViewRepresentable?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have an old `OldNSView : NSView`, which is embedded in SwiftUI `NewView<S:SomeProtocol> : NSViewRepresentable` struct. And I need to add a context menu. But when I try to create `NSMenuItem`s for `oldNsView.menu`, they asks for `#Selector`, which needs `@objc func ...` to work. Because it's inside SwiftUI `View` compiler doesn't allow to do it. (With no `#selectors` defined I can see menu items labels (of course they are greyed-out and they do nothing).

On the second hand, If I try to add `.contextMenu` to SwiftUI `newView` nothing happens. No menu at all. It works with `Text(...)` or another generic views but not with custom `NSViewRepresentable` struct.

All `mouseUp(with event..)`, `mouseDown()`, and `mouseDragged()` call `super.mouse..(with event)`

if I use Coordinator

```
public class Coordinator: NSObject {
    ...
    //Compiler does't like if (_ sender: OldView).
    //It likes (_ sender: NSView), but in this case context menu is grayed-out
    @objc func changeXAxis(_ sender: NSView) {
        if let view = sender as? OldView {
            print ("changeXAxis") 
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You have coordinator concept in representable to handle interaction with `NSView`.

Here is simple demo. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / macOS 10.15.5

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoViewWithMenu: NSViewRepresentable {
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = NSView()

        let menu = NSMenu()
        let item = menu.addItem(withTitle: "Do Action", action: #selector(Coordinator.action(_:)), keyEquivalent: "")
        item.target = context.coordinator
        
        view.menu = menu
        return view
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        @objc func action(_ sender: Any) {
            print(">> do action here")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK. But what if my `NewView : NSViewRepresentable` is in fact `SpaceButton<Vertex:SpaceVertexProtocol> : NSViewRepresentable {...}`? I like and need this view to be generic.